# How do I install/use flowplayer with my drupal 7?

Tags: 7

I am a complete beginner to drupal and I am currently working on a project to set up a live streaming website. I am using iis7 as my web host and I want to integrate it with WOWZA server. I've been trying to follow this guide(http://www.ebremer.com/encore/originalproject) that uses swftools to embed flowplayer but the module is not available for drupal 7 so I'm trying to manually configure flowplayer to work with my website. I've successfully installed Flowplayer API module and downloaded the free version of flowplayer onto my server in sites/all/libraries/flowplayer like the readme.txt for the flowplayer api tells me to. But I go into admin/configuration/media/flowplayer on my drupal site it tells me that I need to install and set up flowplayer. How would I do that?

Comment: Did you checkout https://www.drupal.org/project/flowplayer?